# AdMob Android 2.2 error

Tags: android, admob

I am using AdMob 6 for android 2.2 and I see this message in the xml layout
"The following classes could not be instantiated:
-  (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details."
When I run my application it says "Unfortunately ... has stopped."

This is what my manifest looks like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" >
        >
```

Is there anything I can do to get this working?
Thank,
-Steven

Comment: Please post the LogCat errors.

Comment: Whats your SDK target? Min? Target should be at least API Level 13 and Min depends on your need for backwards compatibillity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `<meta-data....>`

as in

```
<meta-data android:value="......" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
<activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" >
        >
```

When you registered your admob account, the publisher id, goes in to the `value` tag.

Comment: The XML is what is giving the error
<com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:anUnitId="MYADCODE"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

Comment: btw check your ads:anUnitId="MYADCODE"... was that a typo there in your comment or is that actually in your code?